# Sync Thunderbird/Lightning contacts, tasks, calendars with GroupDAV?

Tags: sync, thunderbird, lightning

I would like to sync my Thunderbird/Lightning contacts, tasks, and calendars with a [Citadel](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/start) groupware server.

The Citadel server requires the GroupDAV protocol to sync. What do I need to do to make Thunderbird and its Lightning extension use the GroupDAV protocol to sync contacts, tasks, and calendars via GroupDAV? Specific instructions would be appreciated. Thanks!

BTW, I use Mac OS X 10.6.7 and sometimes Linux systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Citadel's site has some directions in their FAQ.](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/faq:favoriteclient:using_your_citadel_calendar_and_contacts_in_thunderbird#using.your.citadel.calendar.and.contacts.in.thunderbird)